# .Net Client request has UTF-8. The response from Java WebService I get back doesn't. How to fix?

Tags: java, c#, web-services, utf-8, soap1.2

So I am trying to consume a Java Web Service, that I don't control, through my .net application. My application sends the request with the header as:

> Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8.

The response I get back has header as:

> Content-Type: application/xop+xml; type="application/soap+xml"

The absence of UTF-8 in response gives me a Communication Exception as follows:

> The content type application/xop+xml; type="application/soap+xml" of the response message does not match the content type of the 
>   binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. 
>   The first 1024 bytes of the response were:

Apparently as per: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3902.txt 
Charset is an optional parameter. So how do I fix this in .net. I have tried various binding combinations but nothing helped.

Comment: I doubt that missing the char set on the response will throw any exception. Better post the full exception info and the calling code with the line where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks @Gusman. I have updated my question with the error I am getting. Sorry, I can't post the code.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10497333/413337 or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31801165/413337

Comment: Thanks @Codo I had done my research before I posted this question. I had tried those solutions and any other binding combination I could and sorry they are not working for me.